# Why computer science does not have a featured questions tab?(questions with bounty)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

I can't find a featured tab in the https://cs.stackexchange.com/ site I have tried looking at the questions page https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions but there is only these tabs:

newest-frequent-votes-active-unanswered

And in the home page of the site I can find these tabs:

active-hot-week-month

I have tried accessing the featured questions by going to the address :

https://cs.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured

And it works But shouldn't there be a permanent link in the site to access the featured questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there:

[image]

I'm not sure why you would not be able to see it. Can you now? Maybe it disappears when there's no featured question.

Comment: There was no featured question at the time, and yes, the tab disappears when there is no featured question.

Answer (score 4):

The “featured” tab lists questions with an ongoing [bounty](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). At the time you posted, there was no question with an ongoing bounty. When the tab would be empty, it is not shown at all.